# How to plot animated time series in R?

Tags: r, ffmpeg

I am trying use the 'animation' package in R to plot an animated time series.

My dataset consists of a time vector and a value vector, each with 1800 rows.

I keep getting an error message after running the loop which reads:

```
Error in jpeg(gname[i]) : unable to start jpeg() device
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In jpeg(gname[i]) : unable to open file 'g11:30:00.jpg' for writing
2: In jpeg(gname[i]) : opening device failed
```

Here's the source code

```
timemax<-1800
setwd("~/Documents/Animation/")
graphdata<-read.csv("filling_line_data_construction_v2.csv")
attach(graphdata)
gname<-paste("g",time, ".jpg", sep="")
for (i in 1:timemax){
    jpeg(gname[i])
    plot(time[1],value[1],type="l",ylim=c(0,35), xlim=c(0,100),
      ylim = c(0, 35),ylab = "", xlab="time")
    lines(time[1:i],value[1:i])
    dev.off(dev.cur())
}
```

The end goal is to string together these 1800 plots as a stop animation video by calling the ffmpeg shell:

```
shell("C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -report -i g%d.jpg -b:v 2048k fillin_lineR.mpg",mustWork=FALSE)
```

This is code that I've been trying to adapt from http://www.animatedgraphs.co.uk/LondonR.html#slide-30, but this example uses a .tif file instead of .jpg, and my computer gives me 1800 error messages when trying to make a video from .tif files...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide the necessary data to reproduce this. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Since you're on Windows, maybe the filenames shouldn't have colons in them.